# Add Label only for eigenvector>10 in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, sna

I have the following code for a network graph:

```
network=ggnet2( NOT1, #the network we plot 
  size = NOT1Geig, #node size in eigenvector 
  max_size = 5, #max size of nodes 
  node.alpha = 0.9, #node opacity 
  node.color = Attriregional1, palette=c("Region"= "red", "Not Region"= "orange"), color.legend = "Organisation", label=FALSE)
```

How to display in the network graph only when eigenvector >10?

When I write `label=NOT1Geig>10`, it says TRUE OR FALSE on the network graph.

Comment: network=ggnet2(
  NOT1,       #the network we plot
  size = NOT1Geig,            #node size in eigenvector
  max_size = 5,         #max size of nodes
  node.alpha = 0.9,      #node opacity
  node.color = Attriregional1,
  palette=c("Region"= "red", "Not Region"= "orange"),
  color.legend = "Organisation",
  label=FALSE)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It would be really neat if there was some kind of minimal reproducible example to play around with to let us help you.

Comment: You can [edit] the post to include your code where it will be more legible